# Error: Could not access key vault reference metadata

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am getting below error for Azure Function App in Azure Portal. This message is displayed under Configuration.

Error: Could not access key vault reference metadata

[image: This message is displayed for all web apps under configuration.]

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one secret named `AppSecret` in my key vault like below:

[image]

You can get the ***Secret Identifier*** of this secret from here:

[image]

I added this in **Application settings** of Function App by referencing it like below:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri="https://srikv.vault.azure.net/secrets/AppSecret/6df69934a6fdxxxxxxxxx")
```

[image]

After selecting *OK* and *Save*, I got the **same error** as you like below:

[image]

> The error usually occurs if **incorrect syntax** is used while
> referencing Key vault that includes ***quotes***/***curly brackets*** around Secret Identifier.

To **resolve** the error, correct the syntax by removing ***quotes***/***curly brackets*** if present around Secret Identifier like below:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://srikv.vault.azure.net/secrets/AppSecret/6df69934a6fdxxxxxxxxx)
```

[image]

After **saving** the above setting, Key vault reference is successful like below:

[image]

Comment: This is how my setting looks like: @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://project.vault.azure.net/secrets/jobsStorageAccountConnectionString/70ab3b985bd843e39dd77bad5a0d218d) I don't see any quotes/curly brackets

Comment: Could you include the snip of that setting from Portal to understand where exactly the issue is?